# How to exit a script after ThreadPoolExecutor has timed out

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm trying to cleanly exit after some work times out because a thread is being blocked by something. I'm using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` like this:

```
try:
  with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as executor:
    # submit some work
    workers = [executor.submit(...) for x in work]
    # wait for completion
    try:
      for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(workers, timeout=60):
        f.result()
    except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
      raise TimeoutError()
except TimeoutError:
  # cleanup
```

This code gets to `# cleanup` no problem, but the script never exits because it's waiting for that blocked thread to finally finish. I do not yet know what is causing the worker to block forever, that's another issue to solve, but i need to have a way to at least exit when we run into this scenario.

I looked at how threads in ThreadPoolExecutor are created and they are being set to `daemon = True` so I'm doubly confused why these threads are blocking the application from exiting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is, strangely enough, intended behavior. From `concurrent/futures/thread.py` (version 3.6.3):

```
# To work around this problem, an exit handler is installed which tells the
# workers to exit when their work queues are empty and then waits until the
# threads finish.
```

"This problem" is exactly the behavior you want - to exit while worker threads are still running. The exit handler mentioned calls `join()` on all the worker threads, which blocks forever if they're stuck:

```
def _python_exit():
    global _shutdown
    _shutdown = True
    items = list(_threads_queues.items())
    for t, q in items:
        q.put(None)
    for t, q in items:
        t.join()

atexit.register(_python_exit)
```

There's also the `__exit__` method of the `TaskThreadExecutor` itself:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.shutdown(wait=True)
    return False
```

`self.shutdown`, with `wait=True`, also joins all the worker threads.

To force exit, we need to override both of these. If you modify your code as follows:

```
except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
    import atexit
    atexit.unregister(concurrent.futures.thread._python_exit))
    executor.shutdown = lambda wait:None
    raise TimeoutError()
```

then your script will exit as desired.

Comment: (Thanks for the edit - not sure where that crept in from.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was tearing my hair out and would not have figured out how to undo their shutdown meddling

Comment: Then, what is the benefit of `daemon=True` if it doesn't fulfil the main purpose?

Comment: Uargh, that's evil because the `atexit.unregister` will disable the regular shutdown of any thread pool executors that you may not even know about.